# Documentum Document Template Import issues

Tags: documentum, documentum6.5, webtop, documentum-dfs

I'm using Documentum Composer to create a new XML application.  After importing an XML template for the content from WebTop, I noticed that the templates are missing the Documentum-Specific attributes such as these:

**Expected:**

**<ArticleTemplate xmlns:dctm="http://www.documentum.com" dctm:obj_status="Read-Only" dctm:obj_id="0123456789ABCDEF" dctm:version_label="CURRENT">**

**Observed:**

**<ArticleTemplate>**

Does anyone have an idea of which object I should look at within Documentum Composer?  Is the problem in the type or in the XML Application?

Comment: I believe that the XML application is not working properly. I believe the XML config is sound but when I import the config into the XML Application folder, I am seeing these issues after importing my article templates via the XML Application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what my issue was.  When you import your dm_config_xml type, remember to remove the .xml extension from the NAME property during the import processs.  DA isn't smart enough to remove the extension even if the file name is the same as the XML Application folder.